# Act on each DynamicData SourceCache items with constraint and pause support

Tags: c#, .net, reactive, rx.net

What I'm trying to do here is to iterate over each item of `SourceCache` with a little time between each run and do some async work over each item. Each item must be processed one after other, the work can't overlap. I put a little constraint after each run. The source cache data can change in any moment, it is not fixed data like the example. This example is working well, but I need a way to pause the processing using a `IObservable<bool>` which send true when more work can be processed and false otherwise.

I don't know if this is the best approach to this problem, but maybe there is another way to do the same. Try to stick to reactive code if possible.

As a side note I'm using Net Framework 4.6.2 and DynamicData 7.1.1, and most important I'm really new to programming (just for fun) and Rx.Net.

```
var data = Observable.Range(0, 20).Select(value => new Work(value));

ISourceCache<Work, int> source = new SourceCache<Work, int>(x => x.Id);

using var populate = source.PopulateFrom(data);

var observ = source.Connect().AsObservableCache();

using var _ = observ.Connect()
    .AutoRefresh(x => x.Status)
    .Filter(x => x.Status == Status.Queue)
    .ToCollection()
    .Select(collection => collection.ToObservable())
    .Switch()
    .Take(1)
    // How to pause just before status change
    .Do(work => work.Status = Status.Running)
    .Select(x => Run(x).ToObservable())
    .Concat()
    .Concat(Observable.Empty<Work>().Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(250)))
    .Repeat()
    .Subscribe();

using var ignore = toggle.Connect();
```

```
private static async Task<Work> Run(Work work)
{
    // This is fixed but the time needed to run each work is not constant
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
    return work;
}

public enum Status
{
    Queue,
    Running
}

public class Work : AbstractNotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private Status _status;

    public Work(int id)
    {
        Id = id;
        Status = Status.Queue;
    }


    public int Id { get; }

    public Status Status
    {
        get => _status;
        set => SetAndRaise(ref _status, value);
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"Id: {Id:000} - Status: {Status}";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some brain crushing sessions I ended with something I can call a solution for my problem.

```
        var toggle = Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5))
            .SwitchState(false)
            .Do(Console.WriteLine)
            .Replay(1);

        var firstWork = observ.Connect()
            .AutoRefresh(x => x.Status)
            .Filter(x => x.Status == Status.Queue)
            .ToCollection()
            .Select(collection => collection.FirstOrOptional(x => true))
            .StartWith(Optional<Work>.None);

        var getWork = Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(250))
            .WithLatestFrom(firstWork, (_, first) => first);

        var selector = toggle.Select(value => value ? 
                getWork :
                Observable.Empty<Optional<Work>>())
            .Switch()
            .Take(1)
            .Where(optional => optional.HasValue)
            .Select(optional => optional.Value)
            .Do(Console.WriteLine)
            .Do(work => work.Status = Status.Running)
            .Select(x => Run(x).ToObservable())
            .Concat()
            .Do(Console.WriteLine)
            .Repeat();

        using var executing = selector.Subscribe();

        using var pauseChange = toggle.Connect();
```

`toggle` simulate a pause and unpause every 5 seconds, but in my case will be the status of a toggle button.

When paused the `selector` return an empty observable with not real work to do.

When unpaused the stream gets one and only one `Work` from collection after an initial due time. Then the background jobs is launched until finished and everything get started again.

In my real case I start with an empty collection this is why I have to do some magic with the `Optional<T>` implementation from DynamicData.

I think this solve my problem but I´m open to another solution.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could simplify the code a bit using BatchIf to pause the updates.

```
/// <summary>
/// Batches the underlying updates if a pause signal (i.e when the buffer selector return true) has been received.
/// When a resume signal has been received the batched updates will  be fired.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="TObject">The type of the object.</typeparam>
/// <typeparam name="TKey">The type of the key.</typeparam>
/// <param name="source">The source.</param>
/// <param name="pauseIfTrueSelector">When true, observable begins to buffer and when false, window closes and buffered result if notified.</param>
/// <param name="scheduler">The scheduler.</param>
/// <returns>An observable which emits change sets.</returns>
/// <exception cref="System.ArgumentNullException">source.</exception>
public static IObservable<IChangeSet<TObject, TKey>> BatchIf<TObject, TKey>(this IObservable<IChangeSet<TObject, TKey>> source, IObservable<bool> pauseIfTrueSelector, IScheduler? scheduler = null)
    where TKey : notnull
{
    return BatchIf(source, pauseIfTrueSelector, false, scheduler);
}
```

Comment: I will check this today. Thanks